# XCode 7.3 beta - how to force strict search for code autocomplete for Objective-C?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, xcode7.3

I'm running into an issue where XCode 7.3 autocomplete searches all possible constants using some kind of weird pattern matching algorithm. The result is that I practically have to spell the entire constant name before autocomplete allows me to press "enter" to select the suggestion.

**How can I force XCode to do old, strict "begins with" autocomplete search algorithm?**

For example, attempting to search for constant `kEditTag`, I would expect it to show up once I type `kEd...`, while currently I have to type `keditta`, to have the suggestion even show up in the autocomplete list, making it rather useless:

[image]

Comment: checking preferences ->text editing -> completion tab may help. probably they added an option for completion types.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Still no solution, I remapped some #define constants into enumerated types

Comment: New Auto-complete is so bad! for some reason container ranks higher than Starts with...  Including when I am obviously typing an enum value into a typed expectation... It sill suggests crazy things.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to XCode -> Preferences -> Text Editing and "Enable type-over completions" . This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

When start to type write 2 or 3 character so xcode can interprete what you want in completion. use **ctrl + space**