# Xcode 7.3.1 autocomplete code completion not working

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autocomplete, code-completion

Ever since Xcode 7.3 the autocompletion or code completion doesn't work properly.

[image: Simple import class and it can't autocomplete]

I have tried:

- Deleting Derived Data folder
- Clean Targets and Build
- Reinstalling Xcode

It does autocomplete after you type it out fully the first time. But if you haven't referenced it once (i.e. like enums) it only shows what you typed out before (not showing full list of enums). Pressing escape doesn't help either.

Any other suggestions? Or anyone else experiencing the same?

Comment: Try **this:** http://stackoverflow.com/a/35624767/6124910 Maybe this help you.

Comment: Thanks, however, all files are in the correct target memberships

Comment: he below code worked for me. Run the following command from Terminal, then relaunch Xcode.

`defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without doing anything, In Build-Settings -> Deployment changing iOS Deployment target from 8.0 to 8.1 resolved the issue for me.

[image]

It also works for XCode 6 as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133039/xcode-6-isnt-autocompleting-in-swift)

Also works on Xcode 8, Simply change the deployment target from iOS 9.0 to iOS 9.1.

Comment: Worked for me, but didn't get the reasone. Any explanation ?

Comment: Works for me. If I release to app store does that mean 9.0 devices wont be able to install? or 9.0 and 9.1? Thanks

Comment: This is the most ridiculous solution I've seen... but it worked for me :D Thank you very much

Comment: I can't find such a path: Build > Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8 has now fixed this very annoying autocomplete issue. So anyone who is still having this problem, update to Xcode 8.

Edit: Please note, this has not solved for others. So your milage may vary. For me, it has fixed without doing anything extra. But they are using their new 'intelligent' autocomplete. Thinking about it, it could be part of the indexing. Deleting the DerivedData folder could help.

Comment: Not so fast...  I've never had autocomplete problems, then it breaks for me when I update to Xcode 8.0.  Hence, I found this thread.

Comment: Seems like I should revisit. I have taken off accepted answer. I cleared the cache and any derived data, if that helps. It seems to be going fine now

Comment: I didn't have this problem before, then today with Xcode 8.1 I can't autocomplete!

Comment: saw this last time in Xcode 4 or 5, but occurs again after upgrading to Xcode 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this answer is too late, I'll share it anyway.

First of all, I've uninstalled Alcatraz and all plugins.

Second, I've followed ElonChan's instructions explained on:

[Xcode 7.3 autocomplete issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242732/xcode-7-3-autocomplete-issues/36530564#36530564)

As a result, autocompletion automagically got back! Thanks @ElonChan.

I hope this answer also solves your problem.

Comment: Never too late. But I have no plugins.

Answer (score 0):

This Happen usually when you are using core Data in your project.(because of automatic indexing of files by xcode not been done) The simple way to avoid this thing is that just click to your project name and clean project come back the same file where you wanna see suggestions type any word and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to set shortcut keys for code completion. **Xcode** -> **Preferences** -> **Key Bindings** -> find **Show Completions** and set whatever non-duplicate keys you want.

[image]