# Objective-C Class Methods Will Not Autocomplete in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, autocomplete

I have Objective-C class methods that will not autocomplete or show up in Swift. I am using xcode 8.1.

I created a test Objc class:

```
// deleteMe.h
@interface deleteMe : NSObject

+ (void)test;

@end

// deleteMe.m

#import "deleteMe.h"

@implementation deleteMe
+(void) test
{
    NSLog(@"y u no autocomplete?");
}

@end
```

In my Swift (which has this imported in the bridging header) I have tried to access this method via autocomplete and it doesn't work:

**Class does not appear for autocomplete**

[image: Class not appearing]

**Class method does not appear for autocomplete**

[image: Class method not appearing]

*If I code it in, it does work:*

[image: It should work]

So if I code it in exactly, it is finding it and the instance is valid as is the class method call.

I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214036/3324388) on updating the deployment target to 8.1 to fix this issue but it did not.

Do you know why autocomplete is not working and ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you seen this post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133039/xcode-6-isnt-autocompleting-in-swift

Comment: Yes thank you, I had tried that before posting this question sadly.