# Xcode 7.3 Objective c class search, has no use prefix

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7.3

Say my prefix is `GV`, and I have a class named `CVViewController`.
Before Xcode 7.3 I use to search for `ViewController` and `CVViewController` would show up first.

After recent update, `CVViewController` will only show up when searching with prefix.
This is probably after Swift doesn't have to use Prefixes any more. But for Objective C this is a pain.

Is there any way to change this back?

Comment: Does that help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36218021/1489885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose what you mean by "search" is by hitting <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, right?

What you describe seems to work fine for me (Xcode 7.3).

Try to do the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26357665/289501) and as an alternative you can use the [FuzzyAutocomplete Plugin](https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin) which should also do what you want.