# Xcode 7.3 intellisense not working at all

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it just mine or is it really a bug? After the update the intellisense seems to be not working at all especially with class declarations. Has anyone filed a bug report for this??

Comment: Does it work with ctrl + space?

Comment: yes but that kills the point of ease doesn't it. It wasn't like this before. Even after ctrl+space it doesnt show the class. Specially happens when you newly import some class and try to declare a variable right after that

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169099/xcode-7-3-autocomplete-is-so-frustrating) help?

Comment: Yes, the answer with the most upvotes there helped my case

Comment: Should I post it as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try removing Xcode's *Derived Data* directory?

Go to **Xcode > Preferences... > Locations**. In *Derived Data* section you'll find path to mentioned directory. Go to that directory, exit Xcode, remove directory and relaunch Xcode.

It helped when I was having issues with code completion.

Answer (score 0):

Press `Command+Shift+Alt+K` and restart "Xcode".

OR

Press `Command+Shift+option+K` and restart "Xcode".

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36218021/1806873) says, try to clear the checkbox "Enable type-over completions" under XCode -> Preferences -> Text Editing to solve problems with auto completion in Xcode 7.3.